# Modeling a subsystem as a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, specifications

I want to make a use case diagram, but I have got a question, concerning this following example:

[image: use case of soda machine]

A user can buy soda from a soda machine.
To buy it it needs the system (of the soda machine).

Scenario:
Aim: User buys soda

1. User clicks on "buy soda"-button of soda machine.
2. System does recognize soda in stock
3. System outputs soda.
4. Use-Case succeeded

But now it looks like system isn't a part of soda machine - what technique can I use, so system is a part of soda machine.

Answer (score 2):

Use case models functionalities of the system itself. You never put there a system as an actor as the system is what you model so it wouldn't make sense. You can (but it's not obligatory) present the system as a rectangle (in your case you call it soda machine and that's all - don't put additional information that there is some let's say IT system behind).

To sum up: Don't show a system you model as an actor on Use case diagram. It's a typical mistake.

Comment: To be correct: use cases are primarily there to show the added value. Functionality is under their hood.

Comment: To complete:  you ever put the "system under consideration" (e.g. the soda machine) or a substystem thereof (e.g. software and all the parts) as actor.  Only distinct external systems that intervene in a use case could eventually appear as secondary actor.